# How to refer to two schemas from a single XML file

Tags: xml, xsd

I am starting with XML and XSD and I want to build an XML file that must match two different schemas I got in my hard drive.

What should I type in `targetNamespace` to reference to files schema1.xsd and schema2.xsd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an XSD, `xs:schema/@targetNamespace` defines the *single* namespace that an XSD governs:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/1" 
           targetNamespace="http://example.com/1">
     ...
```

In an XML document, you **can** hint about multiple XSDs, one for each namespace used in your XML document instance via `xs:schemaLocation':

```
<ns1:root xmlns:ns1="http://example.com/1"
          xmlns:ns2="http://example.com/2"
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.com/1 ns1.xsd
                              http://example.com/2 ns2.xsd">
    <ns2:a/>
</ns1:root>
```

In an XML document, you **cannot** hint that a single XML document instance must simultaneously adhere to multiple XSDs (other than for separate namespaces).  You could, however, validate sequentially once per XSD you wish to apply to the XML.